# Programmatically stop/start charging rooted Android LG K4

Tags: android, battery, rooted-device

I found the file sys/devices/platform/battery/LGBM_AtCmdChargingModeOff which has the value of "0".
When I set it to 1, the phone stop charging.

```
String command1 = "chmod 777 /sys/devices/platform/battery/LGBM_AtCmdChargingModeOff;";
String command2 = "echo \"1\" > /sys/devices/platform/battery/LGBM_AtCmdChargingModeOff;";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command1, command2}, null);
proc.waitFor();
```

When I try to set it back to 0, it keep staying at 1. I don't get any failure, so some other process must re-write the file (when /i try to do it manually, I get "error saving the file").
After restart of the phone, the file's value is back to "0". 
Any idea how to get the phone charging again, without restarting it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and was looking for a solution for the past 3-4 years!

There is an app on the Google Play Store called [Battery Charge Limit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slash.batterychargelimit), however it is not maintained anymore and doesn't work with alot of (newer) phones.

Finally, I found this project! [Advanced Charging Controller (ACC)](https://github.com/VR-25/acc) ([Magisk fork](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/acc)).
`"ACC is primarily intended for extending battery service life"`.
It's a Magisk module, but you can make it work with any root solution.
I'm running it on 3 phones and it appears to work so far!

It comes with awesome features such as these:

```
acc -d 70% (do not recharge until capacity drops to 70%)
acc -d 1h (do not recharge until 1 hour has passed)
acc -e 30m (recharge for 30 minutes)
acc -s endurance+ (a.k.a, "the li-ion sweet spot"; best for GPS navigation and other long operations)
acc -s travel (for when you need extra juice)
```

*Background why I need this feature:*

I develop a Raspberry Pi + Android phone solution, where the phone is plugged-in and charging 24/7, such that the battery remains at 100% charge all the time. Li-Ion batteries don't like it and will start to expand inside the phone and damage the device, sometimes to a point where they break. I have to replace batteries every 1-3 years, and in some cases even randomly after approx. 6 months (the price range for the used android phones is around $100-200, usually LG K4 and Moto G/E phones). Now my goal is to keep the battery at a comfortable charge level (around 40-60%) and hopefuly make it last longer.